# Yii Framework: validate checkbox on view page

Tags: view, yii

I'm new to the Yii Framework. Currently, I'm having a project which require me to use Yii framework. I would like to ask, is it possible for me to validate an attribute which is not save inside the database?

case:
I have a checkbox which require the user to tick on it in order to move to the next page. If the user doesn't tick on it, then it will prompt an error. How to I validate it in Yii format?

Can someone teach me how to change the validation below to fit Yii Format? where should the validation locate?

content in model.php

```
public $pdpa_agree;

public function rules()
{
    array('pdpa_agree', 'required');
}
```

content in view.php

```
<?php 
$form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm',array(
    'id'=>'pdpaPolicy-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'type'=>'horizontal',
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
        "autocomplete"=>"off", //turn off auto complete in FF
    )
));
?>

<?php echo $data->pdpa_content; ?>

<p class="cb_pdpa" style="font-weight:bold"><?php echo $form->checkbox($data,'pdpa_agree'); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;I have read and understood the above policies and hereby give consent for CTES to use my <pd>*personal data</pd> in accordance to the policies listed out above.</p>

<div class="form-actions">
    <?php 
    /*$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'buttonType' => 'submit', 
        'type' => 'primary', 
        'label'=>$model->isNewRecord ? 'PolicyAgreement' : 'Continue Registration',
    ));*/
    ?>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Continue Registration" onclick="validateAgreement()">
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

<script>
function validateAgreement()
{
    if($("#pdpa_agree").is(':checked'))
    {
        window.location.href = 'register?sourceID=CTES';
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please tick on the agreement checkbox in order to proceed the registration!");
        return false;
    }   
}
</script>
```

How to turn to validation below to fit Yii Format?

```
<script>
function validateAgreement()
{
    if($("#pdpa_agree").is(':checked'))
    {
        window.location.href = 'register?sourceID=CTES';
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please tick on the agreement checkbox in order to proceed the registration!");
        return false;
    }   
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can validate

```
Model.php
```

Delclare the variable you want to use

```
public $pdpa_agree;

public function rules()
{
    array('pdpa_agree', 'required');
}
```

public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'pdpa_agree' => 'I have read and understood the above policies and hereby give consent for CTES to use my *personal data in accordance to the policies listed out above',
        );
    }

MyController.php

```
public function actionRegistration(){
   $model = new Model();

   if(isset($_POST['Model'])){
       //Stuff to save Goes here
   }
   $this->render('registration');
}
```

view.php

```
<?php 
$form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm',array(
    'id'=>'pdpaPolicy-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'type'=>'horizontal',
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
        "autocomplete"=>"off", //turn off auto complete in FF
    )
));
?>

<?php echo $data->pdpa_content; ?>

<div class="form-actions">        
    $form->checkBox($model,'checkBox');
    $form->labelEx($model,'checkBox');
    $form->error($model,'checkBox');
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. Then I would like to know, how can I do the validation?

Comment: what validation do you need?

Comment: Hi i have edited the question above. I would like to know how can I change the validation above to fit Yii format? where should I place the validation?

Comment: Btw,where is the validation function goes?

Comment: enableClientValidation => true does the client validation based on model